# mean per group in a fragmented dataset

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series

this is actually an extension of my previous question, but I was requested to put it as a separate question
[Rolling average on previous dates per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74138848/rolling-average-on-previous-dates-per-group)

I have the following dataset:

```
Name    Loc     Site    Date    Total
Alex    Italy   A   12.31.2020  30
Alex    Italy   B   12.31.2020  20
Alex    Italy   B   12.30.2020  100
Alex    Italy   B   12.28.2020  40
Alex    Italy   A   12.23.2020  80
Alex    France  A   12.28.2020  10
Alex    France  B   12.28.2020  20
Alex    France  B   12.23.2020  10
Alex    France  A   12.23.2020  100
Alex    France  B   12.21.2020  25
```

I want to add per each row the average of total in arbitrary time frame before the Date per Name, Loc and Date

This is the outcome I'm looking for previous 5 days (excluding Date):

```
Name    Loc    Site Date      Total Prv_Avg
Alex    Italy   A   12.31.2020  30  70
Alex    Italy   B   12.31.2020  20  70
Alex    Italy   B   12.30.2020  100 40
Alex    Italy   B   12.28.2020  40  80
Alex    Italy   A   12.23.2020  80  NaN
Alex    France  A   12.28.2020  10  55
Alex    France  B   12.28.2020  20  55
Alex    France  B   12.23.2020  10  25
Alex    France  A   12.23.2020  100 25
Alex    France  B   12.21.2020  25  NaN
```

The Nulls are for rows where there are not 5 previous days in the data

Comment: Should not the first two values of column `Prv_Avg` be 100 instead of 70?

Comment: No, for 31.12, It will calculate for 30.12 and 28.12 (both are within 5 days, not including 31.12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom lambda function in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with replace match values to NaNs and create averages by [`numpy.nanmean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])


def f(x):
    arr = x.index.to_numpy()
    s = x.to_numpy()
    prev = arr - pd.Timedelta(5, 'day')
    return np.nanmean(np.where((arr[:, None] > arr) & 
                               (arr >= prev[:, None]), s, np.nan), axis=1)


df['Prv_Avg'] = (df.set_index('Date')
                   .groupby(['Name','Loc'])['Total']
                   .transform(f)
                   .to_numpy())
print (df)
   Name     Loc Site       Date  Total  Prv_Avg
0  Alex   Italy    A 2020-12-31     30     70.0
1  Alex   Italy    B 2020-12-31     20     70.0
2  Alex   Italy    B 2020-12-30    100     40.0
3  Alex   Italy    B 2020-12-28     40     80.0
4  Alex   Italy    A 2020-12-23     80      NaN
5  Alex  France    A 2020-12-28     10     55.0
6  Alex  France    B 2020-12-28     20     55.0
7  Alex  France    B 2020-12-23     10     25.0
8  Alex  France    A 2020-12-23    100     25.0
9  Alex  France    B 2020-12-21     25      NaN
```

Comment: Hi, @jezrael, good morning! I am not sure the expected output of the OP is consistent. For France, your result does not match the expected output. Also my solution for the previous question of the OP, that should work also for this new question, does not match the expected output for Italy.

Comment: @PaulS - Yes, seems 110 not match by sample data, I guess typo. Or OP need something else ;)

Comment: Hi, I've checked my output and it is consistent, it should not show 110 in any case in my example

Comment: @Alex - If check output of `print (s)` there is `2020-12-30    100.0`, so it is 3 days after `2020-12-28     40.0`. So why expected ouput is `12.28.2020  10  55` ? How is count `55` ?

Comment: @jezrael, for group of Alex + France, if you look on 28.12.2020, I need to see the mean of previous 5 days, excluding 28.12. Thus, the mean of 23-27.12. In this case, the only relevant day is 23 with two samples - 100 and 10, hence the mean of 55.

Comment: @Alex - Answer was edited.